# Scroll through multiple divs from anchor to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have another question.
Recently I am trying to build a page with three divs. Each of them has a height of 100vh and a width of 100vw.
The thing I want to archive is, that if I am scrolling in div 1 that it automatically scrolls smooth to the top of div 2. And so on. I hope that you understand my question.

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**fullpage.js**](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  scrollOverflow:true
});
```

```css
.section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}

.section:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.7/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha256-e13jRNqOX98m6UAwI/yZTpcDseJtA8s86yfFs4Sqrv8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.7/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js" integrity="sha256-R7CttZ4L0/szai0hbFUlPDiRaEJmqYuvLhyAOr19vQg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so far! It worked, but I got stuck at a further point. I included the fullpage.js. Over the fullpage.js I included the scrolloverflow.js. But the options scrolloverflow makes this error:
"
fullPage: The option `scrollOverflow:true` requires the file `scrolloverflow.min.js`. Please include it before fullPage.js."

Any Ideas?

Comment: @Undelivered i updated the demo with scrolloverflow